# Unity IL2CPP cause very slow XCode build

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I've start to use IL2CPP as Scripting Backend in Unity 4 and 5.
This cause the XCode project generated by Unity to build the project in about 2 minutes as apposed to when I use Mono which was built in less then 30 seconds.

Do other people notice the same problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, building in Xcode is much slower with IL2CPP. The Mono scripting backend emits platform specific assembly code, so the XCode build does not need to build any of the script or engine code. The IL2CPP scripting backend generated C++ source code, so Xcode has more to compile.

Note that we at Unity are working on this issue, specifically providing incremental build support so that subsequent builds will be much faster.